# data type to store precision more than double in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, gaussian, floating-point-precision

I an working in matlab, recently I am doing research in image processing. this time I  am implementing a research paper [this paper](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c8e651zoyhxzg5d/2007.pdf), in which I am getting problem to store precision more than double. kindly check the equation 6 of that paper.

I am facing problem in following code..

```
img = imread('Einstein.bmp');
exponent = double(zeros(size(img,1),size(img,2)));
s = double(zeros(size(img,1),size(img,2)));
sigma=1;
for i=1:size(img,1)
    for j=1:size(img,2)
        exponent(i,j) = double(((i^2)+(j^2))/(2*(sigma^2)));
        s(i,j) = double(exp(-exponent(i,j)));
    end
end
```

After some values, s(i,j) gives 0 for all values but that values should not be 0. how can I avoid that problem?

Comment: If you are running out of precision with a `double`, then it sounds like your values are inappropriately scaled. I would first scale all of your input values to make more adequate use of the precision of a double, then un-scale your outputs at the end.

Comment: What is the exact problem? Do you really need more than the ~16 decimal places of precision that a `double` gives you, or is it something else? A calculation returning `0` when you know the answer should be nonzero? There are high precision tools available for Matlab, but they are almost never needed. The problem is generally solved by a few tiny modifications to your code.

Comment: I have to concur with Chris and Jonathon. If `double` is not enough, 999 out of 1000 times it's a problem with your code and/or design rather than a real precision requirement. Could you please post the relevant parts of the code, and the associated errors/unexpected outcomes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, it seems you are trying to create a [2D Gaussian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#Two-dimensional_Gaussian_function) centered at (0,0). The kernel width you are using is really small: `sigma=1`, seeing you are computing the function over the entire grid of an image pixels. So no wonder you are getting all zeros except for a tiny portion in the top-left corner of the matrix `S`.

Here is a more efficient way to create the kernel centered around the middle:

```
% 100x100 grid
r = 100; c = 100;
[x,y] = ndgrid(1:r,1:c);

% sigma = 20
sigma = max([r c])/5;

% 2D gaussian function
z = sum(bsxfun(@minus, [x(:) y(:)], [r c]./2).^2, 2);
z = exp(-z ./ (2*sigma^2)) ./ (sigma^2 * 2*pi);
z = reshape(z, [r c]);
```

If you have access to the Statistics toolbox, use [`mvnpdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvnpdf.html) to it write as:

```
z = mvnpdf([x(:) y(:)], [r c]./2, eye(2)*sigma^2);
z = reshape(z, [r c]);
```

or if you have the Image processing toolbox, simply use [`fspecial`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html#bqkft1d):

```
z = fspecial('gaussian', [r c], sigma);
```

The result:

```
imshow(z, 'DisplayRange',[], 'InitialMag','fit')
axis on, colorbar
```

[image: 2d_gaussian]

Note that the matrix is normalized so that the integral is one (hence the small values). That's why I turned off the default `[0,1]` range when displaying as an image.

You could also simply map it into `[0,1]` range using: `z = (z - min(z(:))) ./ range(z(:))`

Here is the resulting matrix when viewed as a surface:

```
surf(x,y,z)
axis vis3d
```

[image: 2d_gauss_surface]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that matlab only uses 64-bit doubles, but you might have luck with one of the [arbitrary](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6446) [precision](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36534) [libraries](http://www.advanpix.com/) available for matlab.

Comment: MathWorks has the Symbolic Math Toolbox and MuPAD which provide symbolic computation and [variable-precision arithmetic](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html). That said, in numerical problems like image processing this is hardly needed... As others have said, it is often enough to first scale the values to avoid overflow/underflow problems